# Use JQuery to move element to another parent and remove original

Tags: jquery, element, removechild

I have two li elements I want to ensure have the same parent ONLY if they have the same city inside their anchor value. They are rendered as:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='/home.aspx'>Calgary</a><span>[+]</span>
    <ul class='courses'>
      <li>Course Name 1</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Remove this ul after grabbing the inner <li> (Course Name) -->
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='/home.aspx'>Calgary</a><span>[+]</span>
    <ul class='courses'>
      <li>Course Name 2</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Leave this ul alone -->
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='/home.aspx'>Montreal</a><span>[+]</span>
    <ul class='courses'>
      <li>Course Name 3</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, please show me how to grab the 'Course Name 2' li and place it under the 'Course Name 1' parent ul. Also, I would like to remove the originating ul marked with 'RemoveMe'.

Comment: why a downvote? Is this question not verbose and clear?

Comment: to better understand your requirements you should add at least one more <ul> element with different name and get rid of that id="RemoveMe" as this will not be set in your case as far as I understood

Comment: thanks. That did add unnecessary confusion

Comment: upvoted to get rid of -1 because this question looks quite tricky and interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something that works, taking the liberty of adding a class called "city" to some of the `li` elements to help differentiate them.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/cT8D8/)

It loops through and finds other anchors share the same text but do not reference the same element.  It then finds the courses in their lists and adds them to the original anchor's list.  I think it could be made clearer by adding additional classes, but the general concept is there.

One thing I hadn't originally counted on was needing to make sure that the elements are still visible.  I grab the array of anchors up top, and they're still referenced even after having been removed.

```
$(function() { 

    $('li.city a').each(function(ix) {

        if ($(this).is(':visible'))
        {

            var $anchor = $(this);
            var myText = $(this).text();

            var $matches = $('a').filter(function() {
                return (($(this).text() == myText) && (this !== $anchor.get(0)));
            });

            $.each($matches, function() {

                var $snip = $(this).parent().find('ul.courses li');

                // add the li elements to the first anchor's list
                $anchor.parent().find('ul.courses').append($snip);

                // bubble up to duplicate anchor's ul tag and remove it entirely
                $(this).closest('li.city').parent().remove();

            });

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Very nice. One thing I don't like is `$('a').filter()...` because in theory there can be more `<a>` elements in page with same text inside outside of `<ul>`. There should be some predefined container element (like `<div>`) around all this. And if so, then you need to make sure to filter only inside this container element. This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/RLF4m/ See first line of HTML - anchor element. That breaks everything.

Comment: @DarkSide - I totally agree.  Personally, I would add class names in a couple more places like the outer `ul` and the `a` tags themselves.  Makes it much easier to hop up and down the DOM and to ensure you're grabbing the *correct* anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, but I admit - I didn't test this piece of code.

```
$("ul").each(function(){
    // get city
    var city = $(this).find("li > a").text();

    // find similar cities
    var other = $(this).siblings("ul").has("li > a:contains('"+city+"')");

    // move LI elements and remove similar ULs
    // not sure, maybe this should be done one by one (using each() for example)
    // that's in case if you have found more than 1 similar entry
    other.find("ul.courses > li").appendTo($(this).find("ul.courses"));
    other.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines would work.

I have given the first `<ul>` an id "Ul1" for simplicity's sake.

```
 var x = $("#RemoveMe").getChildren().first();

    if( $("#RemoveMe").getChildren().eq(1).text() == $("#Ul1").getChildren().eq(1).text())
{
    $("#Ul1").getChildren().first().append(x);

    $("#RemoveMe").getChildren().first().remove();
}
```

A more generalised solution:

```
$("li").each(function(){
  if ($(this).getChildren().first().text() == "some city name")
 {
    $("#Ul1").getChildren().first().append($(this));
    $(this).remove();
 }  
});
```

Note: I suggest giving these particular `<li>` some particular class name to use as a selector.

Comment: The OP is also asking for help identifying "if they have the same city in their href". It might also be better if you don't use `.first()` since elements with the same href may not be the first.

Comment: thanks guys. Yes, we can assume the <a> will be the first child. But we cannot assume #RemoveMe is unique which this code does. The condition should be if they have the same City

Comment: are you aware that there can only be a single element with the same id  ( #RemoveMe) ?

Comment: the RemoveMe id was to show the element I wanted removed. Sorry if this caused confusion. Edited OP

Comment: I have added a more generalised solution for you in addition to the original one. Using one of them (or both) you should manage :)

Comment: In generalized solution you need to use `ul > li` selector otherwise each() will work also for ul>li>ul>li which we don't want. And it uses hard-coded "some city name" which is wrong

Comment: regarding ul>li that is why I suggested using a class name, makes the job so much simpler. Regarding the hard coded name, that will have been obtained before the .each() loop and stored as a variable, possibly as shown in the more specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id='AddToMe'>
  <li>
    <a href='/home.aspx'>Calgary</a><span>[+]</span>
    <ul class='courses'>
      <li>Course Name 1</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='RemoveMe'>
  <li>
    <a href='/home.aspx'>Calgary</a><span>[+]</span>
    <ul class='courses'>
      <li>Course Name 2</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('#AddToMe a').text() == $('#RemoveMe a').text()){
       $('#RemoveMe').find('.courses li').appendTo($('#AddToMe .courses'));
       $('#RemoveMe').remove();
   }
});
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKa9H/3/)

EDIT NOTES - added the removal of the "RemoveMe" id ul
EDIT 2 - added if condition to compare anchor tags

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't check for equal anchors or names at all (author need that).